# How to update all records one field with two other fields combination?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying two update all records one field with two other field combination and with a random number as showed below

Table Company

```
Id  Name   Telephone Total
1   Test1   032       (randomNumber)Test1.032
2   Test2   022       (randomNumber)Test2.022
3   Test3   111       (randomNumber)Test3.111
```

Total Field should be update as above.

I am using Oracle and i have more than 100.000 records that should be update in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sorta have 3 different patterns for the `Total` column.. can you give more detail?

Comment: JamieD77, basicly in total field should be combination of (randomNumber)+name+"."+telephone+

Comment: So where are you stuck? You certainly know how to update a table. And you certainly know how to concatenate strings. And you've certainly googled how to generate a random number. So what problem persists?

Comment: I am new in sql, After many different try i wrote a question. I cant make a update of a field with 3 different combination. Should i write all my attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE  Company
SET total = '(' 
           || ( trunc( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,1000) )) 
           || ')' || Name || '.' || Telephone
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kordirko. It works perfectly. Just how can i make name to be in lowercase ?